# How to save the settings from my Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, settings

I'm currently making a wordpress plugin with a settings page, where the user can input images, names and URL's which will then be shown on the website using a widget and a shortcode. Of course, I want to save these settings so they can be shown on the website.
I have found this code, but I don't know if it is the (best) way:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>
    <p><strong>One 1:</strong><br />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('name'); ?>" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Logo" name="logo" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('logo'); ?>" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Website" name="website" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('website'); ?>" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="name, logo, website" />
</form>
```

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) from Wordpress, there is all you need to create an option page.

Comment: That's very useful! Feel stupid I didn't think about that... Thank you!